# For loop of an array

Tags: php

I want to make check of array by using **for** loop. The check is if selected value display it also display its index.

Comment: What do you mean? What have you tried so far and why didn't that work?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you are asking but my guess would be a [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop

```
$array = array("hello" => "world");

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  echo "This is my index " . $key . " with it's value " . $value;

}

//prints This is my index hello with it's value world
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have index by `$key` using `foreach` will help you.

```
for($array as $key=>$value){
if($selectedvalue){
echo $key." ".$value ;

}


}
```